# Testing $on AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm testing that a controller is able to pickup a broadcast. Here's the the `$on` part inside of the controller:

```
$scope.$on('gridService_chkdItems', function() {

        if( $scope.pageModel.chkdItems !== undefined  ) {
            $scope.pageModel.chkdItems = [];
        }
        $scope.pageModel.chkdItems = gridService.getChkdItems();  
        $scope.$apply();
    });
```

And inside my test I'm doing the setup like so:

```
beforeEach( inject( function($injector) {
  rootScope =  $injector.get( '$rootScope' );
  scope = rootScope;
  spyOn( scope, '$on' );
}));
```

In my test I'm checking if the `$on` service picks up the target event by doing the following:

```
 it( 'should pick up the chkdItems broadcast on the grid service',function() {
   expect( scope.$on ).toHaveBeenCalledWith( 'gridService_chkdItems', Function );    
 });
```

It fails and gives me an odd error that essentially says that it was called with what I expected but still fails - why is this?

```
Expected spy $on to have been called with [ 'gridService_chkdItems', Function ] 
but actual calls were [ 'gridService_chkdItems', Function ]
```

Comment: I think you're testing the wrong code. Testing if AngularJS calls the right event handler isn't your task. This is done by the AngularJS developers. You should test the logic of your event handler when an event occurs.  
Also try to avoid calling $apply() in an event handler. If the event  itself is fired from outside angularJS, wrap the broadcast in an $apply.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I'm the angular dev charged with testing the code. What I didn't add here which came afterwards was the that the logic inside the event is being triggered but to determine that correctly you need to know if the event is actually being picked up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your expect to be based upon `any` function.

```
expect( scope.$on )
  .toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    'gridService_chkdItems', 
    jasmine.any(Function));
```

Comment: That works - thanks! But if i'm passing a function object and its expecting a function object what does the test fail?

Comment: They are different references